# Set comparison in R

Tags: r, set, comparison

Hi I have a two massive big table(>10 million rows) that contain two IDs in random order. Each row can be seen as a pair, how can I get the unique overlap between two tables? I know in python you can define object in set, is there a similar function in R? Many thanks!

Table 1

```
ID1 ID2
10  15
150 10
23  24
26  71
```

Table 2

```
ID1 ID2
10  15
15  10
23  28
26  71
```

Ideal output

```
ID1 ID2
10  15 (count once only!)
26  71
```

Comment: Removed the data.table tag. It isn't relevant, I think

Comment: @docendodiscimus I think they are mentioning sets and "random order" because `10 15` and `15 10` are to be treated equivalently, since each row is a "set". This distinction isn't important in the example data, though.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the elements of each pair so that merging works:

```
pairs1 <- unique(t(apply(DF1,1,sort)))
pairs2 <- unique(t(apply(DF2,1,sort)))

merge(pairs1,pairs2)
#   V1 V2
# 1 10 15
# 2 26 71
```

With dplyr, you can also do

```
library(dplyr)
intersect(pairs1, pairs2)
```

which has a more intuitive name when it comes to comparing "sets".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `semi_join` or `anti_join` from the package dplyr. But there are other strategies too:

```
table1<-data.frame(id=c(1:5), animal=c("cat", "dog", "parakeet", 
"lion", "duck"))
table1
##   id   animal
## 1  1      cat
## 2  2      dog
## 3  3 parakeet
## 4  4     lion
## 5  5     duck

table2<-table1[c(1,3,5),]
table2
##   id   animal
## 1  1      cat
## 3  3 parakeet
## 5  5     duck

# strategy 1
table1[!table1$id%in%table2$id,]
##   id animal
## 2  2    dog
## 4  4   lion

# strategy 2
table1[is.na(match(table1$id,table2$id)),]
##   id animal
## 2  2    dog
## 4  4   lion

# strategy 3. anti join
library(dplyr)
anti_join(table1, table2, by="id")
##   id animal
## 1  2    dog
## 2  4   lion
```